# Deploy and build my go app on my server

Tags: linux, macos, git, go

I'm totaly new to go (it looks fabulous btw).

So I want to build a "web-"app in go with the revel framework. The problem is I code on my mac (os : darwin, arch : amd64) and I want to deploy the app on my server (os : ubuntu 12.04, arch : amd64).
I "go get" revel in local (so `bin/revel` it's a: Mach-O 64-bit executable) which is non executable on my server.

For now when I push (with git), I've got a post-receive script to build the app (`revel build myapp /path/to/deploy`). Before I've tried to "go get" revel on my server, but it failed too.

It's not working, I could understand why, but I don't have any idea how to get a workable workflow :

1. Code on my mac
2. Push my code (with git)
3. Build the app on the server

PS: I've read http://blog.gopheracademy.com/auto-deploy-revel-site, http://revel.github.io/manual/deployment.html as well as articles about cross-compilation)

Comment: If you've read about cross-compilation and deployment, what exactly is your question? What *exactly* is failing for you?

Comment: At first I did : a push my project without revel and with my post-receive I rm my existing directory, and try to go get revel. I had an error "not a git repository". Now I thought that I could cross-compile my project but revel (which I commit now) is a Mach-O 64-bit and I can't execute it with my post-receive. So I would like to know how I can set a workflow to deploy my app with these parameters (coding on mac os x and running on ubuntu 12.04). Sorry for my lack of precisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps.. but here goes..

Your exact situation is what I am currently doing daily whilst I develop my first proper web app in Go. I develop on both a Windows laptop (whilst bored at work.. I'm a .NET developer at my workplace!) and my Mac at home. I then deploy it to an Ubuntu server hosted on Digital Ocean.

My workflow is:

- Make any changes.
- Commit to repository (BitBucket)
- Pull from repo (wherever that may be - e.g, on my Ubuntu server)
- `go build` the code in place on the server
- `go get` any libraries that it complains about which I don't have on the server (for example, `gorilla/mux` wasn't on the server today so I just ran that)
- `go build` again (if applicable)

..then just run it on the server.

When starting with this workflow (which I am still trying to perfect with bash scripts, etc ...) I found that a consistent `GOPATH` across environments really helps.

For example, my `GOPATH` on each machine is:

- Windows: `C:\GOPATH`
- Mac: `~/go-code/`
- Linux: `/home/simon/go-code/`

Each of them have exactly the same structure:

- $GOPATH

  - src

    - github.com/

      - gorilla/
      - revel/
      - etc.../
    - Simon

      - WebApp1 <--- git repo

        - .git
        - src
      - WebAPp2
      - WebApp3

...etc. This greatly simplifies the entire thing and is what allows me to develop across 3 environments seamlessly.

I am still getting used to Go and this setup (being a .NET developer at my core) - but it seems to be doing the trick for now.

Comment: Than you very much for you reply and your explanations. It works good for me now, and I'm able to deploy my build app on my server. I will use your workflow.

Answer (score 4):

The simple, easy to test way is to cross-compile a Linux amd64 binary on your Mac and push *the binary* over to your server using scp/Fabric/other tool of choice here. There's no need to then fetch deps (and risk breaking things), build anything on your server: you just ship a binary.

**Option 1**: http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go - and then build the binary using `go-linux-amd64 build` or by setting the environmental variables directly (as per the below option).

**Option 2**: install Go using Homebrew `brew install go --cross-compile-common` and then run `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build` - or use the `-o` flag to specify a different output filename. I typically output mine as `myapp-linux` so it doesn't overwrite the platform native binary.

Comment: I agree with building locally. We have found that having servers build the application is just bad news and error prone and hard to automate.

Comment: Yeah +1. Like I said in my answer - I am still getting used to the Go ecosystem so my process isn't the best - but workable for me for now.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for you reply. The only thing working is cross-compile.

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, I wanted to code on mac and deploy on Linux. This quick and dirty way worked for me on Go 1.6.2 http://kumargaurav.co/2016/08/10/deploy-go-lang-app-linux-server/